# Link in top of list item

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, navbar, listitem

I have bootstrap navbar and i want the links in the top of the list item

```
        <li>
          <a class="menuLinks" href="http://news.bootswatch.com">Blog</a>
        </li>
```

CSS:

```
  .menuLinks {
        vertical-align:top;
  }
```

I tried this too:

```
  .menuLinks {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
  }
```

and it didn't work too.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this properties:

```
display:table-cell;
height:40px;
vertical-align: top;
```

Answer (score 0):

Need more information to know what you want to do. If its positioning the element, you can change that in your css with margins etc. Or if you want it above other elements then you need to move the html code above those elements. If you display more of the code it might make it easier to help you.

Comment: I have li in height of 40px, I want the link on top of it in 0px height.

Comment: Try in your css `margin-top:-40px;` this will move the element up 40 pixels.

Comment: Display all code so I can see it in my browser and be more helpful. :)